# Java: array attribute in object

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am a newbie in Java programming and was just wondering if you can do this:
I have a object class Person:

```
public class Person {

    public String name;
    public String[] friends;
}
```

If yes how to initialse it, i.e.

```
newPerson.name = "Max"; 
newPerson.friends = {"Tom", "Mike"};
```

I tried to do it like that, but it does not work.

Comment: You need to create an instance first. ```Person p = new Person();```

Comment: If you are a newbie, then start by studying Java tutorials. You can't expect to learn Java by asking 500 questions on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
new Person("Max", new String[]{"Tom", "Mike"});
```

You would also need a constructor to initialize the variables.

```
public Person(String name, String[] friends){
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = friends;
}
```

As a good practice, you should also limit the access level of variables in your class to be private. (unless there is a very good reason to make them public.)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a constructor. You may want to mention that making fields public is not a good practice.

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622730/why-are-instance-variables-in-java-are-always-private

Answer (score 1):

try

`newPerson.friends = new String[]{"Tom", "Mike"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
public static class Person {
    public String name;      
    public String[] friends;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    newPerson.name = "Max";
    newPerson.friends = new String[] {"Tom", "Mike"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats actually pretty simple

U can initialize in creation (thats the easiest method):

```
public class Person {

      public String name = "Max";
      public String[] friends = {"Adam","Eve"};
 }
```

U could initialize variables in your constructor

```
public class Person {
      public String name;
      public String[] friends;
      public Person(){
          name =  "Max";
          friends = new String[] {"Adam", "Eve"};
      }
 }
```